# HIVE: no column names in output

Tags: hive, hiveql

[This is how it typical looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r1pZ.png)

I use PuTTY for running Hive queries. Query results have no column names.

Setting doesn't have obvious check-box for "add column names", not to me anyways...

Can you help please?

Thanks

More details: [Issue description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ur2l.png)

Comment: Please add some additional information as question seems to be incomplete. You can use this as reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: command line looks something like this:      hive -f test.hql  > test1_result.txt                                 The text file then contains no name of the columns..

Comment: Added a screen shot above ("This is how it typical looks")

Comment: I cannot see where is PuTTY involved in this issue. Please put the content of `test.hql` into the question (or the relevant part of it) and tag the question with [tag:hive] or other tags related to the technology you use.

Comment: Added a screen shot with more details. The issue I'm having is how data is shown. I thought it is PuTTY settings issue or something. If it not, perhaps you can point me to a right direction as to where to look for answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this command once in your hive session:

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
```

Alternatively add this command in .hiverc file in your home directory. See this for reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-ThehivercFile